# Noun vs Suffixes '-ism' vs 'ity'

Tags: difference, suffixes

> In his [Sir Stephen Sedley]'s view:
>
> > The notion that the prime function
> >     of human rights and indeed the Rule of law is to protect the weak against the
> >     strong is not mere **sentimentality**.

Source: p 43, *The English Legal System 2012-2013*, Gary Slapper

1. What's the big picture behind similarities and differences? I ask not only about sentimentality here. I can't access [this resource](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/secondary/pocket_fowlers_modern_eng_usage/ism-and-ity), so I resorted to Etymonline:

> [-ism](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ism&allowed_in_frame=0): suffix forming nouns of action, state, condition, doctrine
>
> .[-ity](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ity&allowed_in_frame=0): 
>   suffix forming abstract nouns from adjectives, meaning "condition or quality of being **__**,

`2.` When are these suffixes redundant, and does the noun itself suffice?

For example, [definition 2 of **sentiment**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sentiment) = [definition of sentimentality](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sentimentality). How and why?

Comment: I am not the person to have that depth of knowledge that it requires to answer this question. But one thing I have noticed in those two links that you have provided. While "sentiment" is "intense emotion", "sentimentality" is exaggerated and self-indulgent. Though I know this is not a complete answer. It's just a simple comment. I don't have anything to add.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, I don't have an answer for your question #2. But I can help you with your question #1. The resources you were trying to access and can't seems to redirect to Fowler's Modern English Usage page. Even I don't have access to that page, but I have an image of that page from that book. Here is that page. Please have a look -

[image]

Download this image from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YPk8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

*-ism* describes a body of thought, philosophy, ideology, doctrine - a way of thinking/collection of knowledge.

Doctrines/philosophies are overarching things that guide and justify behavior.  So there is this tendency to attach *-ism* to something that guides/justifies behavior, especially if it's perceived as bad, opporessive, and this extends to things that aren't ideologies/doctrines per se but just as controlling/justifying of behavior.

> His absenteeism is getting bad.
>
> Sexism is something we strive to avoid in this workplace.
>
> Alcoholism is a disease.

*-ity* is just one way to turn an adjective into a noun, to talk about a quality as a thing of itself.  It's very commonly used to "noun-ify" adjectives that end in *-able*.

> He is respectable -> Respectability is something I want in a person.